# "new Random(x)" always generates the same numbers?

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to get a unique random number but i always get the same number every time i run the code. i will get 14 first then 6 but my list for holding all the used numbers doesn't seem to work.adding the 14 manually works but when i add randInt it doesn't work.

```
const int numCards = 32;
        List<int> usedCards = new List<int>();
        int randInt = 0;
        Random rand = new Random(numCards);
        usedCards.Add(14);
        do
        {

            randInt = rand.Next(0, numCards);
            MessageBox.Show(randInt.ToString(), "End Game", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        while (usedCards.Contains(randInt));

        usedCards.Add(randInt);
```

Comment: @Alexei: that's a different mistake -- that's making a new `Random` on every use.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "almost", but this is more ... specific. A good related question, however.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace:

```
Random rand = new Random(numCards);
```

with

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Supplying a *fixed* seed value (`numCards` always has the same value) in the [`Random` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx) call will result in a *predictable*, *reproducible* sequence which is always the same for the same seed value, just like this (not quite but still the point is valid):

[image]

For example using a fixed seed of `1` and drawing 10 numbers ranging from 0 to 100,  on my machine *always* produces the sequence

```
24,11,46,77,65,43,35,94,10,64
```

Using no seed value on the other hand, the sequence becomes unpredictable.

Without a seed value passed in, `Random`  will generate a new seed value based on the current time, that's what you want to get a new sequence of random numbers - provided you don't initialize it again in fast order, that's why you should re-use `Random` instances instead of re-creating them every time.

Comment: Sorry, this needs to be included for situations like this: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @David Z.: Why? That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: thanks that works now i believe. now on to other problems with my code

Comment: Very good answer. Very nice picture :) You found the part of an algorithm of programs in Casino. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

If you specify a seed value to the Random class constructor, it will generate the same sequence every time. The algorithm to produce the random number sequence is deterministic.

If you use the constructor without parameters, the Random object will use a seed value on the current time, so each Random object instantiated using this constructor will have a different sequence of random numbers as long as the time seed value is different which is likely.

You can still get the same sequence of numbers from two different Random objects if they are initialized very close in time to each other.

[Random Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx)